using grep inside make to check if a file contains an export to PATH
I'd like a make function that checks if the given path is already exported in my .bashrc/.zshrc/etc. file.
Since you have to double and triple escape things (shell + make + regex) I got stuck. My current attempt:
define ensure_in_path
    @rg='export\s+PATH\s*=\s*\"\\$$PATH:${1}\"'; \
    if ! cat "${1}" | /bin/grep -q -E $$rg ; then \
        echo "added \"${2}\" to exports in \"${1}\".";\
    fi
endef

What I would like to match something like this export\s+=\s*\"?\$PATH:<the path here>\". (Is this even a good match?)
Example:
$(call ensure_in_path,$$HOME/.bashrc,$$HOME/.local/bin) should check if export PATH="$PATH:/home/<username>/.local/bin" is in /home/<username>/.bashrc and if not append it to it.
It would of course be nice to also expand the paths inside .bashrc before checking them, but that's a question for another day.
Edit 1:
Working bash version:
pth="$HOME/.local/bin"
rg="export\s+PATH\s*=\s*\"?\\\$PATH:${pth}\"?"
cat $HOME/.bashrc | grep -qE $rg

Still not working make version:
define ensure_in_path
    @rg="export\s+PATH\s*=\s\"?\\\\$$PATH:${2}\"?"; \
    echo $$rg;\
    if cat "${1}" | /bin/grep -qE $$rg ; then \
        echo "added path..."; \
    fi 
endef

It's not escaping $PATH correctly.

The first step is to write a plain shell script that works and get that quoting correct.  Once that works, to add it into the makefile you need to escape all the $ as $$.  But before we can really help we need to see how this is used in an actual makefile; the context of where the call appears can make a big difference.  Hopefully your makefile isn't really mucking around with users' .bashrc files!

BTW, cat filename | grep ... is a UUOC. Use grep ... filename

@MadScientist thanks for reminding me of the most basic of troubleshooting steps :D. Bash version is working but I'm still confused about ho to do the escaping with the make one.
And no, this is not for production or anything like this. I just hate myself and decided to put all my configuration for my PC into one Makefile...

@Barmar I had echo in there before and just didn't remove it, but yes UUOC indeed.

I think it comes down to being able to print $PATH (the literal, not the path). But when doing $$PATH it prints the contents of the envvar. when trying to escape it via \$$PATH it just prepends a . I think $$PATH is evaluated before even given to sh (just a wild gues though.)
I could do printf "$$%s" "PATH" but this is would be a very ugly workaround.

Well, the version in the makefile you show above, is not the same at all as the one in the shell script.  I'm not sure why you decided to make extra changes.  For example, you added an extra backslash.  But you're making things more difficult for yourself by using double-quotes; there's no need for double-quotes when you're using make variables because make just expands its variables regardless of where they appear.
Also just to point out, it's illegal in a shell script to put whitespace around the = when assigning a variable.  VAR=foo is valid; VAR = foo is illegal.
If this works in a shell script:
grep -qE 'export\s+PATH="?$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"?' < $HOME/.bashrc

then the equivalent of this for a makefile (where $1 is $HOME/.bashrc and $2 contains $HOME/.local/bin would be:
grep -qE 'export\s+PATH="?$$PATH:$2"?' < $1

